# Stationary probability in an M/M/$1$ queue with a lazy server

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, queueing-theory, operations-research

> Customers arrive to a single server queue according to a Poisson
>   process with rate $\lambda$. Each customer requires Exponential($\mu$)
>   service time. In the beginning when there are $0$ customer, the server
>   idles (i.e. ignores the customers) until the number of customers
>   reaches $n$. As soon as there are at least $n$ customers, the server
>   begins working and *serves every customer until the system is
>   completely cleared (i.e. until there are zero customers).* Then the
>   server idles again until the number of customers reaches $n$ again.
>
> Find the stationary probability that the system has zero customer.

Define state space $S=\mathbb{N}_0 \cup \{1_u,2_u,\ldots, (n-1)_u\}$. The states with subscript $u$ are the idle states where the server does not serve. I model this system as a continuous-time Markov chain illustrated by the following state diagram:
[image: State diagram]

Let $p_s$ denote the stationary probability of the process being in state $s\in S$. Since $p_{1_u}\lambda=p_1\lambda$ and $p_{i_u}\lambda=p_{(i-1)_u}\lambda$ for $i=2,\ldots,n-1$, we have $p_{i_u}=p_0$ for $i=1,\ldots,n-1$. Then I can write out the balance equations in terms of only the $p_i, i\in\mathbb{N}_0$:$$
\begin{aligned}
p_0\lambda &= p_1\mu \\
p_1 (\lambda+\mu) &= p_2 \mu \\
p_2 (\lambda+\mu) &= p_1 \lambda + p_3 \mu \\
&\vdots \\
p_i (\lambda+\mu) &= p_{i-1} \lambda + p_{i+1} \mu \\
&\vdots \\
p_{n-1}(\lambda +\mu) &= p_{n-2} \lambda + p_n \mu \\
p_n(\lambda+\mu) &= p_0 \lambda + p_{n-1}\lambda + p_{n+1} \mu \\
p_{n+1}(\lambda+\mu) &= p_{n}\lambda + p_{n+2} \mu \\
&\vdots \\
p_{j}(\lambda+\mu) &= p_{j-1}\lambda + p_{j+1} \mu \\
&\vdots
\end{aligned}
$$

I have been stuck from this point on. I did try writing out $p_1$ in terms of $p_0$, and $p_2$ in terms of $p_1$ (and hence $p_0$), and so on, trying to find an inductive pattern. I tried up to $p_5$, but still cannot see any clear pattern. Could anyone give some help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider a "renewal time" as a time when the number of customers goes from $1$ to $0$.  After a renewal time, we wait Exponential($\lambda$) time in each of the states
$0, 1_u, \ldots, (n-1)_u$: a total expected time $n/ \lambda$ of which an expected time $1/\lambda$ is spent in state $0$.  Then the server becomes active, and we are
in a "normal" M/M/1 queue until the customers are cleared (presumably $\lambda < \mu$ so this will actually happen).  The expected time for that is $n/(\mu - \lambda)$.  So the total expected time between renewals is $n/\lambda + n/(\mu - \lambda)$, of which an expected time $1/\lambda$ is spent in state $0$.  Thus the
equilibrium probability of state $0$ is 
$$\dfrac{1/\lambda}{n/\lambda + n/(\mu - \lambda)} = \dfrac{\mu - \lambda}{n\mu}$$

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, divide through $\lambda + \mu$ to get the probability, then use the fact that that $\frac{\lambda}{\lambda + \mu} + \frac{\mu}{\lambda +\mu} = 1$ and construct difference equations. Can you handle from here?